# Plus construction of sheafification as a colimit of presheaves.

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

In *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic*, Moerdijk and Mac Lane construct the associated sheaf on a site $(\mathcal C, J)$ of a presheaf $P$ as
$$ a(P) = (P^+)^+ ,$$ 
where $P^+$ is defined pointwise as $P^+(U) = \underrightarrow{\mathrm{lim}}_{R \in J(U)} \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Psh}(\mathcal C)}(R, P)$. Then they prove that $P^+$ is a presheaf (satisfying some properties).

I wonder if one could skip the last part (proving that $P^+$ is a presheaf) by defining $P^+$ direclty as a colimit **in the category $\mathrm{Psh}(\mathcal C)$** rather thant pointwise. I tried to find out that colimit without success, principally because the pointwise compuation makes the indexing family dependant of the point. So is it possible ? If so, could someone give me a hint ? If not, what is the reason ?

Comment: Colimits in the category of presheaves *are* computed pointwise.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, but with a fixed indexing category, right ? Namely, for a diagram $A : I \to \mathrm{Psh}(\mathcal C)$, one have for $U$ object of $\mathcal C$ $(\underrightarrow{\mathrm{lim}}_I A)(U) = \underrightarrow{\mathrm{lim}}_I A_U$ where $A_U$ is the diagram $A_U(i) = A(i)(U)$ for $i$ object of $I$. I'm trying here to find the $I$ and $A$ for $P^+$.

Comment: No, I don't think there's any shortcut here, precisely because the indexing category is different from one place to the next. By formal nonsense there _is_ a diagram whose colimit computes $P^+$ for a given $P$, but it's not obvious to me whether the diagram depends on $P$ or not.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, that was precisely my question (the dependence on $P$ of such a diagram). The existence of the diagram by itself does not interest me per se. I would have been happy to find an expression of the diagram with respect to $P$.

Answer (score 4):

There is a shortcut via Kan extensions.  I learned it from section 6.2.2 of *Higher Topos Theory*, which treats the case of sheaves of simplicial sets on a general site.  Here's what it looks like for sheaves of sets on a topological space.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the frame of open subsets of some topological space $X$.  Let $\text{Cov}(\mathcal{C})$ be the poset in which an object is a pair $(U, \mathfrak{U})$ of an object $U$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and an open cover $\mathfrak{U}$ of $U$, and $(U, \mathfrak{U}) \leq (V, \mathfrak{V})$ if $U \subseteq V$ and $\mathfrak{U}$ is a refinement of $\mathfrak{V}$.  Let $\mathcal{C}^{+}$ be the poset of triples $(U, \mathfrak{U}, U')$ such that $(U, \mathfrak{U})$ is an object of $\text{Cov}(\mathcal{C})$ and $U'$ is a subset of some element of $\mathfrak{U}$, and $(U, \mathfrak{U}, U') \leq (V, \mathfrak{V}, V')$ just in case $(U, \mathfrak{U}) \leq (V, \mathfrak{V})$ in $\text{Cov}(\mathcal{C})$ and $U' \subseteq V'$.

There are three projection functors
$$
e : \mathcal{C}^{+} \to \mathcal{C} \qquad \pi : \mathcal{C}^{+} \to \text{Cov}(\mathcal{C}) \qquad \rho : \text{Cov}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{C}
$$
and the plus construction is the composite
$$
[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}, \mathsf{Set}] \xrightarrow{e^{*}}
[(\mathcal{C}^{+})^{\text{op}}, \mathsf{Set}] \xrightarrow{\pi_{*}}
[\text{Cov}(\mathcal{C})^{\text{op}}, \mathsf{Set}] \xrightarrow{\rho_{!}}
[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}}, \mathsf{Set}]
$$
where the functor $e^{*}$ is pullback along $e$, the functor $\pi_{*}$ is the right adjoint of the pullback $\pi^{*}$, and the functor $\rho_{!}$ is the left adjoint of the pullback $\rho^{*}$.  So $P^{+}$ is a presheaf because the plus construction is a functor, giving the shortcut you want.

These adjoints are given by pointwise Kan extensions, so for any $U$ we can compute $P^{+}(U)$ using (co)limits.  Some finality arguments show that we recover the definition you give of $P^{+}(U)$.